# ValueError with mismatched target and input size

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, dcgan

I am new to machine learning and have been playing around with implementing DCGAN models as a requisite for the research I am doing. I have a somewhat basic model but everytime I run it, regardless what loss function I select as my criterion, I always get a similar message about input and output size being mismatched and I don't know what to do. The stacktrace is as follows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\PycharmProjects\ctgan\dcgan.py", line 148, in <module
> dcgan.train()
> File "c:\PycharmProjects\ctgan\dcgan.py", line 101, in train
> errD_real = criterion(output_real, label_real)  # Calculate the loss with the reshaped >labels
> File "C:.conda\envs\DL_IDS\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1511, in >_wrapped_call_impl
> return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:.conda\envs\DL_IDS\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1520, in >_call_impl
> return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:.conda\envs\DL_IDS\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 725, in >forward
> return F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target,
> File "C:.conda\envs\DL_IDS\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 3197, in  >binary_cross_entropy_with_logits
> raise ValueError(f"Target size ({target.size()}) must be the same as input size ({input.size()})") ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([64, 1])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([2304]))

The full code for my DCGAN model is as follows:

```
import torch
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision.utils as vutils


class DCGAN:
    def __init__(self, dataset, nz=100, ngf=79, ndf=79, nc=3):
        self.nz = nz
        self.ngf = ngf
        self.ndf = ndf
        self.nc = nc
        self.dataset = dataset

        # Initialize the networks
        self.netG = self.Generator(nz, ngf, nc)
        self.netD = self.Discriminator(nc, ndf)

        # Define the loss function and optimizers
        self.criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
        self.optimizerG = optim.SGD(self.netG.parameters(), lr=0.0002, momentum=0.9)
        self.optimizerD = optim.SGD(self.netD.parameters(), lr=0.0002, momentum=0.9)

    class Generator(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, nz, ngf, nc):
            super(DCGAN.Generator, self).__init__()
            self.main = nn.Sequential(
                nn.ConvTranspose2d(nz, ngf * 4, 4, 1, 0, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 4),
                nn.ReLU(True),
                nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 4, ngf * 2, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 2),
                nn.ReLU(True),
                nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 2, ngf, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf),
                nn.ReLU(True),
                nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf, nc, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
                nn.Tanh()
            )

        def forward(self, x):
            return self.main(x)

    class Discriminator(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, nc, ndf):
            super(DCGAN.Discriminator, self).__init__()
            self.main = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(nc, ndf, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
                nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
                nn.Conv2d(ndf, ndf * 2, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 2),
                nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
                nn.Conv2d(ndf * 2, ndf * 4, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 4),
                nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
                nn.Conv2d(ndf * 4, 1, 4, 1, 0, bias=False),
                nn.Sigmoid()
            )

        def forward(self, x):
            print("input shape :", x.shape)
            if x.dim() == 3:
                # Add a batch dimension
                x = x.unsqueeze(0)

            x = self.main(x)
            return x.view(-1, 1)

    def train(self, num_epochs=10):
        # Data loading and preprocessing
        # Remove unused variable
        # transform = transforms.Compose([
        #     transforms.Resize((81, 393)),
        #     transforms.ToTensor(),
        #     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)),
        # ])

        # dataset = self.dataset
        # dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

        device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

        # Sigmoid Cross Entropy Loss
        criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()

        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
            for i, data in enumerate(dataloader, 0):
                # Update Discriminator
                self.netD.zero_grad()
                real_data = data[0].to(device)
                batch_size = real_data.size(0)

                # Create real labels (1s)
                label_real = torch.full((batch_size, 1), 1.0, device=device)  # Adjusted to match the dimensions

                output_real = self.netD(real_data).view(-1)
                label_real = label_real.view(-1, 1)  # Reshape label_real to match the shape of output_real
                errD_real = criterion(output_real, label_real)  # Calculate the loss with the reshaped labels
                errD_real.backward()

                noise = torch.randn(batch_size, self.nz, 1, 1, device=device)
                fake_data = self.netG(noise)

                # Create fake labels (0s)
                label_fake = torch.full((batch_size, 1), 0.0, device=device)  # Adjusted to match the dimensions

                output_fake = self.netD(fake_data.detach()).view(-1)
                errD_fake = criterion(output_fake, label_fake)
                errD_fake.backward()
                self.optimizerD.step()

                # Update Generator
                self.netG.zero_grad()
                label_real.fill_(1.0)  # Adjusted to use float labels
                output = self.netD(fake_data).view(-1)
                errG = criterion(output, label_real)
                errG.backward()
                self.optimizerG.step()

                if i % 100 == 0:
                    print('[%d/%d][%d/%d] Loss_D: %.4f Loss_G: %.4f'
                          % (epoch, num_epochs, i, len(dataloader),
                             errD_real.item() + errD_fake.item(), errG.item()))

            # Save generated images for every epoch
            fake = self.netG(torch.randn(64, self.nz, 1, 1, device=device))
            vutils.save_image(fake.detach(), f'fake_samples_epoch_{epoch + 1}.png', normalize=True)

        # Save the generator model
        torch.save(self.netG.state_dict(), 'dcgan_generator_weights.pth')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Example usage:
    # my_dataset = datasets.CIFAR10  # Set your dataset class dynamically
    transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(79),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)),
    ])
    my_dataset = datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
    dataloader = DataLoader(my_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
    dcgan = DCGAN(dataset=dataloader)
    dcgan.train()
    pass
```

I have tried to expand, resize, reshape my data in all sorts of manner I could find online but none of it seems to yield any meaningful outcome. How to resolve this?

Comment: I have been grapling with this problem for days and have gained some insight in the process. One of which is that the discriminator is outputting a tensor with the wrong shape which, part of the reason for this is that the training loop is configured to process one data point (image in this instance) per iteration yet the discriminator seems to be configured to do batch processing and thus the dimensionality mismatch at the loss function. I hope this comment is helpful towards reaching a solution.